# Connecting Spring + JPA web application with MySQL

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-boot

I have been reading how to make web application using spring from the Getting Started Guides, specifically the following guides:

- Serving Web Content with Spring MVC
- Accessing Data with JPA

But I could not figure how the JPA selected which database driver to store data into.

How can I connect to MySQL database in Spring + JPA.

I learned about Spring + Java Annotations (No XML configurations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guides you mention all use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Spring Boot is a new Spring project that is used for bootstrapping Spring projects. In your case it will auto-configure the datasource for you. Specifically if you have `H2` or `HSQL` on the classpath, Spring will create that in-memory database.

You can easily override the defaults provided by Spring Boot by adding the following properties to `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://whateverhost/whateverdbname
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

For more information check out the [relevant documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource).
Or you can check out [this](http://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/bootstrap-an-application-with-spring-boot-part1-command-line/) tutorial

Comment: In Boot 1.1, you don't need to specify driverClassName for many databases, including MySQL, as Boot will figure it out from the url. See DriverClassNameProvider (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DriverClassNameProvider.java#L38-L48) for details of the databases for which driverClassName is unnecessary